# points decodePath function, having geometry directly

Tags: graphhopper

in graphhopper the points are encoded then decoded in javascript
but i'd like to have the points not encoded, how is it possible ?
is there a php alternative of the decodePath(encoded, is3D) function ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is only a Javascript and Java version at the moment in GraphHopper but it shouldn't be hard to write one in PHP. Or see the [docs](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/web/api-doc.md#routing-web-api-docs) on how to disable encoded polylines.